# How to build a heap out of a list in python

Tags: python, heap

I'm given a list and I am to create a function that heapifys this list as well as count all the steps it took to complete this process. I'm brand new to heaps so I have little to no idea what to do.

I kind of understand WHAT a heap is, but I don't know how to apply this knowledge. So I know that for a max heap, you have the top of your heap `i` and for items on the left of this the rule is `2i` and for the items on the right you have `2i+1`.

Basically as far as I've gotten is

```
def heapify(list):
     count = 0 #so I can count the steps
     i = 1
     left = 2 * i #left family
     right = 2 * i + 1 #right family
     root = i #top of the tree
```

Comment: I feel like something has gone wrong, this is the first time I've asked a question and it hasn't been commented on or answered within 2 minutes. have I missed some information or broken some sort of rule that I'm unaware of

Comment: "it hasn't been commented on or answered within 2 minutes" Have you done something wrong? Wildly unreasonable impatience is probably part of it.

Comment: If you read it properly, it is the first time a question hasn't been answered within two minutes for me and it was just very surprising so I was wondering if there was some sort of accident cause I'm guessing I've asked at least 30 questions so when they are all answered very quickly and then I have a question go unanswered for 2 hours it does raise questions for myself. thanks for your input though, it was very informative